# How to give raw bytes as parameter to C program

Tags: python, c, byte

I'm working on an online CTF challenge and I need to somehow give raw bytes to this compiled C program. I've tried the following using python:

```
./program `python -c 'print "\x00\x00"'`
```

... but for some reason that doesn't seem to be giving me what I'm expecting. Is there some conversion/formatting that's happening that I'm not aware of? I would expect this to give raw bytes as an argument.

Comment: What do you mean "give raw bytes"? Do you mean to pass them as command line arguments?

Comment: Try using `"\x01\x01"` instead.  I suspect you, along with the C library, are confusing an array of N bytes, all of which are zero, with an empty string.  (If you're doing what I think you're doing: yes, that means your shellcode cannot have any zero bytes in it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line args in C are an array of 0 terminated strings. There is no way to pass "raw bytes" (any 0 byte won't behave as expected).

I'd suggest passing either reading the bytes from stdin or from a file specified on the command line.

Comment: Is there a way to pass non-printable ascii characters though? That would accomplish the same thing - for my use case.

Comment: You could encode them in some way (like passing a bunch of 2 digit hex values) and decode them in the C

Comment: @0x23hgww45 Yes there is, and you are doing it already, as long as those bytes are not zero.